# Formatting filename with Date in Windows File Explorer

Tags: date, logging, format, filenames

I'm using MSI Afterburner to output logs of my hardware temps and usage.
I want to include the current date in the filename so that each time I start the program, it creates a new file to log to.

Is there a way I can have Windows include a formatted date in a filename?
Like "Log_dd-mm-yy_hh-mm-ss.hml"

Comment: Can you clarify, what exactly you are doing now and what you want to achieve? Do you want to alter the Afterburner Settings from outside the program to modify the logfile's name to include the date?

Comment: I was hoping that Windows would have a built in way to include system info in a file name. `<Month><Day>` or `%Hour%%Second%` something like that

Comment: No, although in batch scripts you can use variables like %time% and %date%. One idea would be to start afterburner with a script that does the following:
(1) Rename `Log.hml` to `Log_$lastdate$.hml` (you'll see what I mean in the next step).
(2) Store current date in a textfile $lastdate$.
(3) Start afterburner.

This way everytime you start afterburner, last time's log file gets last time's date appended, while Afterburner always saves its log file as `Log.hml`.